# Tricks compiler uses to compile basic arithmetic operations of 128-bit integer

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86-64, compiler-optimization

I played on GodBolt to see x86-64 gcc(6.3) compiles the following codes:

```
typedef __int128_t int128_t;
typedef __uint128_t uint128_t;

uint128_t mul_to_128(uint64_t x, uint64_t y) {
  return uint128_t(x)*uint128_t(y);
}
uint128_t mul(uint128_t x, uint128_t y) {
  return x*y;
}
uint128_t div(uint128_t x, uint128_t y) {
  return x/y;
}
```

and I got:

```
mul_to_128(unsigned long, unsigned long):
        mov     rax, rdi
        mul     rsi
        ret
mul(unsigned __int128, unsigned __int128):
        imul    rsi, rdx
        mov     rax, rdi
        imul    rcx, rdi
        mul     rdx
        add     rcx, rsi
        add     rdx, rcx
        ret
div(unsigned __int128, unsigned __int128):
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    __udivti3 //what is this???
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

3 questions:

1. The 1st function(cast `64-bit` uint to `128-bit` then multiply them) are
   much simpler than multiplication of 2 128-bit uints(2nd function). Basically, just
   1 multiplication. If you multiply 2 maximums of 64-bit uint, it
   definitely overflows out of a 64-bit register...How does it produce
   128-bit result by just 1 64-bit-64-bit multiplication???
2. I cannot read the second result really well...my guess is to break 64-bit number to 2 32-bit numbers(says, `hi` as higher 4 bytes
   and `lo` as lower 4 bytes), and assemble the result like
   `(hi1*hi2)<<64 + (hi1*lo2)<<32 + (hi2*lo1)<<32+(lo1*lo2)`. Apparently
   I was wrong...because it uses only 3 multiplications (2 of them
   are even `imul`...signed multiplication???why???). Can anyone tell me
   what gcc is thinking? And it is optimal?
3. Cannot even understand the assembly of the division...push stack -> call something called `__udivti3` then pop stack...is `__udivti3` something
   big?(like table look-up?) and what stuff does gcc try to push before the call?

the godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/g/sIIaM3

Comment: 64 bit x86 multiply is a 64bit, 64 bit -> 128bit operation.

Comment: If you're going to be looking at assembly language output from the compiler you need to find a reference for it, as there is too much that goes on that is not obvious with just reading the output.

Comment: I recommend you to look up `mul` in the instruction set reference, then everything is clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right that multiplying two unsigned 64-bit values can produce a 128-bit result. Funny thing, hardware designers know that, too. <g> So multiplying two 64-bit values produces a 128-bit result by storing the lower half of the result in one 64-bit register and the upper half of the result in another 64-bit register. The compiler-writer knows which registers are used, and when you call `mul_to_128` it will look for the results in the appropriate registers.

In the second example, think of the values as `a1*2^64 + a0` and `b1*2^64 + b0` (that is, split each 128-bit value into two parts, the upper 64 bits and the lower 64 bits). When you multiply those you get `a1*b1*2^64*2^64 + a1*b0*2^64 + a0*b1*2^64 + a0*b0`. That's essentially what the assembly code is doing. The parts of the result that overflow 128 bits are ignored.

In the third example,`__udivti3` is a function that does the division. It's not simple, so it doesn't get expanded inline.

Comment: As for the use of `IMUL`: In an N x N -> 2N bit multiply, the low-order N bits of the result are identical between signed and unsigned variants, only the high-order N bits differ. Here, we need only the low-order N bits of two of the partial products, so `IMUL` works fine for those.

Comment: More like, calling convention designers intentionally chose the return-value register RAX (and RDX for the high half if needed) in a way that matches `mul` output.  The use-case of literally returning a `mul` result might have been part of the motivation for that design choice, as well as those regs being needed as temporaries.  Your phrasing makes it sound like callers know about looking in RDX:RAX as something special because of what this function does, not just the return type, which hopefully isn't what you meant.

Comment: `udivti3` stands for Unsigned Division of Tetra-Int (`4 * sizeof(int)` ) values.  Not sure exactly what the `3` means; it can't be number of args or number of outputs since the compiler isn't passing any extra output arg.

Answer (score 4):

1. The `mul rsi` will produce a 128 bit result in `rdx`:`rax`, as any instruction set reference will tell you.
2. The `imul` is used to get a 64 bit result. It works even for unsigned. Again, the instruction set reference says: *"The two- and three-operand forms may also be used with unsigned operands because the lower half of the product
   is the same regardless if the operands are signed or unsigned."* Other than that, yes, basically it's doing the double width equivalent of what you described. Only 3 multiplies, because the result of the 4th would not fit in the output 128 bit anyway.
3. `__udivti3` is just a helper function, you can look at its disassembly to see what it's doing.